# effect on area shape map

Tags: html, css, dictionary

I have an image mapped with area shape and I want when I go hover an area make an effect (like create a border or apply some opacity).
This is my code:
How can I do that? I have tried with some class and apply hover with a border or opacity but nothing

```
<img src="img/mappa/mappa.jpg" alt="mappa del parco" usemap="#Map" />
            <map name="Map" id="Map">
              <area  shape="rect" data-fancybox-group="fancy"  coords="307,293,399,351"  id="fancybox" href="#inline1" alt="" class="area"/>
            </map>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unfortunately, this can't be done with css only, as browsers don't allow you to style map areas. you'll have to look for a solution in javascript or flash - if you're already using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) in your site i'd recommend using [this plugin](http://davidlynch.org/blog/2008/03/maphilight-image-map-mouseover-highlighting/) for example ([see a demo](http://davidlynch.org/projects/maphilight/docs/demo_world.html)).

Comment: It's exactly what I search! Perfect